# when creating a custom lib react seem to be unavailable

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack

When building I get the following error message:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/my-components-lib/src/components/table/Table.js 11:4
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (11:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|                }) =>
|
>     <table>
```

Table component in `node_modules/my-compoenents-lib`

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {FormattedMessage} from 'react-intl';

const Table = ({ columns, actions, data}) => <table ...> ... // the error is on this line
```

Usage of table component in `src`

```
import Table from "my-components-lib/src/components/table/Table";
...
return (<Table ...>...)
```

webpack.common.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    entry: [
        './src/index.js'
    ],
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
            favicon: './src/assets/favicon.ico',
            template: './src/index.html',
            filename: './index.html',
            envVarsPath: contextPath +  constants.envVarsFileName
        })
    ],
    output: {
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: [/node_modules/],
                use: ['babel-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jp(e*)g|svg)$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'url-loader',
                    options: {
                        limit: 8000, // Convert images < 8kb to base64 strings
                        name() {
                            // prod -- path will get "/" before images
                            const url = 'images/[hash]-[name].[ext]';
                            return prod ? '/' + url : url;
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
};
```

webpack.dev.config.js

```
module.exports = merge(common, {
    mode: 'development',
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './src',
        hot: true,
        open: true,
        historyApiFallback: true
    },
    devtool: 'inline-source-map'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are importing table component incorrectly. If you are writing directly name of component or folder name without using dots (./), react will try to import this component from node_modules. try to import correctly your component.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are suggesting. It doesn't seem like an import problem, it looks more like babel cannot get to this place to convert JSX to JS

Comment: hope [this link](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/173) will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve the problem by adding this script:

```
  "scripts": {
      "prepare": "rm -rf dist && mkdir dist && babel src/components -d dist/components --copy-files"
  },
```

Looks like it needs to be compiled to JS.